# Which Set implementation in Collectors.toSet()?

Tags: java, set, java-stream, java-11, collectors

I have the following code:

```
Stream.of(1, 4, 5).collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

From [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toSet--) of `toSet()` method one can read:

> There are no guarantees on the type (...) of the Set returned

I took a look at the actual implementation of `toSet()` method and at a first sight it looks like `HashSet` is always returned (at least in JDK 11).

I know that implementation can change in the future without violation of the contract but is there currently any situation when different implementation than `HashSet` is returned?

Comment: No, it is always a hashset, but as the docs say: do not depend on it, never depend directly on implementation Details. If you for some reason require a hashset an no other type of set works, just convert the set you got.

Comment: Keep in mind that `Stream` is an interface; there could be arbitrary implementations, not only those provided by the JRE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. The [JDK source code](https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk/jdk11/file/1ddf9a99e4ad/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/stream/Collectors.java#l303) clearly shows that `Collectors.toSet()` always uses `HashSet::new`. As you say, that may of course change.

Answer (score 5):

As of JDK 11, the type of `Set` returned by `Collectors.toSet()` is a `HashSet`.  This can, of course, change in future versions of Java, and you should therefore not rely on this.

If you wish to use a specific type of `Set`, you should use `Collectors.toCollection` instead, and provide a lambda to create a collection of your choosing.

Answer (score 3):

Use [Collectors.toCollection](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toSet--) for different Set implementation:

> ```
> // Accumulate names into a TreeSet
> Set<String> set = people.stream().map(Person::getName).collect(Collectors.toCollection(TreeSet::new));
> ```

Answer (score 3):

To answer your second question there is

```
Collectors::toUnmodifiableSet
```

since `java-11`,  that returns an immutable `Set` that were added in java-9.

Answer (score 1):

Collectors toSet() returns a Collector that accumulates the input elements into a new Set. There are no guarantees on the type, mutability, serializability, or thread-safety of the Set returned. This is an unordered Collector i.e, the collection operation does not commit to preserving the encounter order of input elements.

If you want to have more control over this, use toCollection instead.